Given $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, does $f(i)=(a*i)\bmod b$, where $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, form a permutation of ${0,1,\dots,b-1}$?
Could anyone be so kind to teach, if the statement is true, and how to prove it mathematically?
I found this statement needs to hold when learning algorithms especially hash related ones. I hence conducted a toy test, and found none violates at least when the two numbers are themselves primes:
def isPermutation( nums, end ):
    """ Check whether nums contains each integer within [0, end) exactly once. """
    assert( len( nums ) == end )
    isNumPresentedArr = [False] * end
    for num in nums:
        if isNumPresentedArr[num]:
            return False
        else:
            isNumPresentedArr[num] = True
    return True


def generatePrimeNums( n ):
    """ Generate all prime numbers smaller than or equal to n """
    n += 1
    nums = [True] * n
    nums[0], nums[1] = False, False
    p = 2
    while p * p <= n:
        i = 2
        while i * p <= n:
            nums[i * p] = False
            i += 1
        p += 1
        while not nums[p]:
            p += 1
    return [i for i, isPrime in enumerate( nums ) if isPrime]

primes = generatePrimeNums( 100 )
for i in range( len( primes ) - 1 ):
    for j in range( i + 1, len( primes ) ):
        a, b = primes[i], primes[j]
        nums = [0] * b
        for k in range( b ):
            nums[k] = ( a * ( k + 1 ) ) % b
        print( isPermutation( nums, b ) )

Thanks in advance.

Yes, if you restrict $f$ to the domain $\{0,...,b-1\}$ (or equivalently take its domain as $\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$), $f$ is indeed bijective (and thus forms a permutation). The idea lies in the fact that $a$ is invertible mod $b$, meaning there exists $u\in \mathbb Z$ such that $au \equiv 1$ mod $b$. All that is needed is to use Bézout's theorem, granting us a couple $(u,v)\in \mathbb Z^2$ such that $au+bv = 1$. Thus we immediately have $au \equiv 1$ mod $b$. Now we can define $g:\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$ such that $g(i) = ui$ mod $b$, and we can easily check that $g = f^{-1}$, proving $f$ is a permutation of $\{0,...,b-1\}$.

Yes
Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there exists integers $u$ and $v$ such that $au+bv=1$. This means that $au=1$ mod $b$, so $u$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $b$.
It is easy to check that the function $g$ defined on $S=\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}$ by $g(k)=ku$ is the inverse function of $f$ (seen as a function from $S$ into itself)
